# how to connect points based on column values in ggplot. (sample code included)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I connect specific points on a plot using ggplot, based on the values of certain columns? I have the solution to this problem using the base plotting system, but I want to know how this task can be done using ggplot.

Code for accomplishing this task using the base plotting system:

```
#Defining the dataset
states <- letters[1:10]
set.seed(12345)
profit.2010 <- runif(10, 1000, 2000)
profit.2011 <- runif(10, 1000, 2000)
data <- data.frame(states, profit.2010, profit.2011)

#Making a plot using base plotting system
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
with(data, plot(rep(1, 10), data[, 2], xlim = c(.5, 2.5)))
with(data, points(rep(2, 10), data[, 3]))
segments(rep(1, 10), data[, 2], rep(2, 10), data[, 3])
```

Incomplete code using ggplot. I have plotted the points. Now how to join these points using ggplot?

```
library(tidyr)
dat <- tbl_df(data)
dat <- dat %>%
        gather(year, profit, -states)
ggplot(dat, aes(year, profit)) + geom_text(aes(label = states))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lines, add a `geom_line` and set the `group=` aesthetic so it knows which points to connect.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(year, profit)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = states)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = states))
```